# Switch audio output by keyboard in KDE Plasma

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, plasma, plasma-widgets

I would like to have a way of switching the audio output device (internal speakers/headphones to bluetooth speakers etc) by keyboard actions (which I usually can do without searching, finding and putting my glasses on my nose).

Plasma tray elements can be activated with shortcuts, and thus I can connect, disconnect, switch between bluetooth devices by keyboard, because when the drop-down menu is visible, selection with arrow-keys and Enter to activate does the trick.

[image]

[image]

But that doesn't work when trying to switch between audio devices themselves. I can bring forth the audio volume tray element with a shortcut:

[image]

but further interaction by keyboard is limited to volume level.

There is a widget called [audio device switcher](https://store.kde.org/p/1195707/) which brings the options more to the front, but its shortcut does nothing. Overall, it lacks keyboard interaction.

The closest thing to what I want is to simply disable bluetooth by the first method *IF* that device is the one that is currently playing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant - you can go by way of scripts/launchers and set the hotkeys to run this scripts.

First you need to get a list of "sinks", which is how system knows audo devices:

```
pactl list sinks
```

One would have state "running" other in "suspended". Take a note of Name fields in this printout.

The script you will start from hotkey will execute a switch:

```
pactl set-default-sink SINK-NAME
```

Using the "Name" field from the list of sinks. This will switch all audio output to specified device.

Assuming you have just two sinks, you can do a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sink1=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_01.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1
sink2=alsa_output.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00.iec958-stereo

sink_current=`pactl get-default-sink`
case $sink_current in
  $sink1) pactl set-default-sink $sink2 ;;
  $sink2) pactl set-default-sink $sink1 ;;
  *) pactl set-default-sink $sink1 ;;
esac
```

Put it into you personal `bin`, and add a hotkey launcher.

Comment: It works just fine!